# PhoneGap Accelerometer application for Android lags like crazy, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, android, dom, cordova, accelerometer

I am using a sample application compiled by PhoneGap and deployed to Android. Lags significantly - my refresh time is set to 100ms and yet you can feel that the acceleration readings only update every 1-2 seconds in a rather "jumpy" fashion. The phone is a single-core  HTC phone running android 2.xx OS. (don't have more details - don't have the phone right now).

Acceleration Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var watchID = null;

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready, start watching
function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

// Start watching the acceleration
function startWatch() {
    // Update acceleration every 3 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 100};

    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, 
         options);
}

// Stop watching the acceleration
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' + 
                        'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration
//
function onError() {
    alert('oooops!');
}

</script>
```

Waiting for accelerometer...
    Stop Watching

Comment: Did you really solve your problem with the accepted answer?

Comment: Nah, it was a little better - but no major improvement.

Comment: help me: all other stuff works on phone, but accelerometer no response error or anything i have tried TONS of things with config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this can help, but it seems changing `innerHTML` with the value only instead of an entire `string` get better performance.

Check out this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-perf

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing on a device or on the simulator?

The simulator has always had a lag for me on osx.

You can try to allocate more memory to the simulator, or look for a more efficient way to code your app.

Comment: No no, I am testing it on a real phone! The data reading seems to lag compared to other similar acceleration sensor reading apps on the market.